# Expect module as global in certain environment

Tags: webpack

I want to craft a webpack config that satisfies an import dependency from the global scope. e.g.,

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

For one webpack config, I want it to be bundled. For another, I want it to grab $ from window instead. Help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the *expose-loader* do define a module global. For this, you have to install *expose-loader* and set up a rule like this:

```
//install expose-loader
npm install --save-dev expose-loader

//set up rule (just relevant parts)
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: require.resolve('jquery'),
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'jQuery'
        }, {
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: '$'
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like it will take my jQuery module, bundle it, and then expose it to global. What I want is for the application to assume that jQuery is already in the global scope, provided by the page or another library within the page. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

I found [NormalModuleReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/) that will do what I want. Use the standard version for my all deps bundle, use a shim that exports the window $ for my version that expects it to already be available.